# How to insert table valued parameters into Sql Azure from Node?

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on an application that inserts data in bulk and in order to reduce the number of queries I wanted to use Table Valued parameters.

Example:

```
var sql = require('node-sqlserver');

var connectionString = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=tcp:serverName.database.windows.net,1433;UID=user@serverName;PWD=password;Database={databaseName};Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;';

sql.open(connectionString, function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to sql', err);
    }

    var tableValuedObject = ???;

    var query = 'usp_InsertSomeTable ?';

    conn.query(query, tableValuedObject, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running insert', err);
        }
    });
});
```

Where  `usp_InsertSomeTable` is defined as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertSomeTable
    @TVP SomeTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO SomeTable (Data) SELECT Data FROM @TVP;
END
```

I have my table valued object defined as

```
CREATE TYPE SomeTableType AS TABLE
(
     Data VARCHAR(50)
);
```

What structure should the JavaScript object have or has that not been implemented in the [Node-SqlServer](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver) project?

Edit 1:

using `var tableValuedObject = { Data: 'Hello World' };` produces an error:

```
node-sqlserver\lib\sql.js:3254: Uncaught Error: [msnodesql] Invalid parameter(s) passed to function query or queryRaw.
```

Edit 2:

using `var tableValuedObject = [{ Data: 'Hello World'}];` produces and error:

```
error running query { [Error: IMNOD: [msnodesql] Parameter 1: Invalid parameter type] sqlstate: 'IMNOD', code: -1 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Node.js application is running on Windows (e.g. in Windows Azure Web Sites), a convenient way of running any SQL commands is to use ADO.NET from .NET Framework within a Node.js process via Edge.js (http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge). Edge.js allows you to run .NET and Node.js in-process.

There is also edge-sql, an Edge.js extension that exposes basic CRUD operations to Node.js using ADO.NET and Edge (http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/06/access-sql-azure-from-nodejs-app.html). While current functionality of edge-sql will not allow you to accomplish what you need here, the implementation of edge-sql itself may be a good starting point for your own (https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge-sql). I also do take contributions to edge-sql if you feel like enhancing its feature set.

Comment: You are not answering to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters to the function `query` have to be passed as an array (see example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx)). Try calling it as such, it should work:

```
sql.open(connectionString, function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to sql', err);
    }

    var tableValuedObject = { Data: 'Hello World' };

    var query = 'usp_InsertSomeTable ?';

    conn.query(query, [tableValuedObject], function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running insert', err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Alright I tried it and it returned: `error running query { [Error: IMNOD: [msnodesql] Parameter 1: Invalid parameter type] sqlstate: 'IMNOD', code: -1 }`

Answer (score 0):

From the source, it currently only supports native sql server types.

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/blob/2ac58c8dda77406f081db693c70f2986b29b6025/src/OdbcOperation.cpp

However, you can run multiple inserts in one query call.

```
var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.test ([key], [value]) VALUES ('1', 'a');" +
"INSERT INTO dbo.test ([key], [value]) VALUES ('2', 'b');" +
"INSERT INTO dbo.test ([key], [value]) VALUES ('3', 'c');" +
"INSERT INTO dbo.test ([key], [value]) VALUES ('4', 'd');" +
"INSERT INTO dbo.test ([key], [value]) VALUES ('5', 'e');";

conn.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running insert', err);
        }
    });
```

O course, you probably won't want to inline your values, in which case you can use parameters and send all the values as an array.